# Index multidimensional torch tensor by another multidimensional tensor

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, tensor, numpy-slicing

I have a tensor *x* in pytorch let's say of shape (5,3,2,6) and another tensor *idx* of shape (5,3,2,1) which contain indices for every element in first tensor. I want a slicing of the first tensor with the indices of the second tensor. I tried x= x[idx] but I get a weird dimensionality when I really want it to be of shape (5,3,2) or (5,3,2,1).

I'll try to give an easier example:
Let's say

```
x=torch.Tensor([[10,20,30],
                 [8,4,43]])
idx = torch.Tensor([[0],
                    [2]])
```

I want something like

```
y = x[idx]
```

such that 'y' outputs `[[10],[43]]` or something like.

The indices represent the position of the wanted elements the last dimension. for the example above where x.shape = (2,3) the last dimension are the columns, then the indices in 'idx' is the column. I want this but for more than 2 dimensions

Comment: How do interpret indices `idx=[[0],[2]]` to get  values `[[10],[43]]` from `x`? It is unclear what those indices represent, are they row/column or flattened array indices?

Comment: It would mean the position in the last dimension which for that example is the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand from the comments, you need `idx` to be index in the last dimension and each index in `idx` corresponds to similar index in `x` (except for the last dimension). In that case (this is the numpy version, you can convert it to torch):

```
ind = np.indices(idx.shape)
ind[-1] = idx
x[tuple(ind)]
```

output:

```
[[10]
 [43]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `range`; and `squeeze` to get proper `idx` dimension like

```
x[range(x.size(0)), idx.squeeze()]
tensor([10., 43.])

# or
x[range(x.size(0)), idx.squeeze()].unsqueeze(1)
tensor([[10.],
        [43.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the one that works in PyTorch using `gather`. The `idx` needs to be in `torch.int64` format which the following line will ensure (note the lowercase of 't' in `tensor`).

```
idx = torch.tensor([[0],
                    [2]])
torch.gather(x, 1, idx) # 1 is the axis to index here
tensor([[10.],
        [43.]])
```