# PyTorch: how to select values from a multidimensional tensor using a multidimensional index?

Tags: python, pytorch

Given a tensor `input` of shape (5, 2, 2):

```py
tensor([[[ 0,  1],
         [ 2,  3]],

        [[ 4,  5],
         [ 6,  7]],

        [[ 8,  9],
         [10, 11]],

        [[12, 13],
         [14, 15]],

        [[16, 17],
         [18, 19]]])
```

and a tensor `index` of shape (2,2):

```py
tensor([[4, 3],
        [4, 2]])
```

How do I obtain the following output:

```py
tensor([[16, 13],
        [18, 11]])
```

To put it into context: I have 5 input images of size 2x2 pixels (stored in `input`). Now I want to combine these 5 images into a single image of size 2x2 pixels, where `index` determines for each pixel from which input image it should be copied.

Example: starting at the top-left `index[0,0] == 4`, I take pixel value `input[4,0,0] == 16`. Then continue to `index[0,1] == 3`, I take pixel value `input[3,0,1] == 13` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found is almost the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62763015/2509417):

```py
indices = np.indices(input.shape)
indices[0] = index
input[tuple(indices)][0]
```

which gives the desired output

```py
tensor([[16, 13],
        [18, 11]])
```